# what are my legal obligations in owning a distillery

Tags: legal, whiskey, help

I am interested in distilling whiskey and vodka. Im not sure of what the legal ramifications are but I want to one) do it legally and two) do it economically. Is this possible and what are the average start up cost for license .

Comment: At the very least, you are going to have to tell us where you are based.  I also very much doubt anyone on this site is going to know enough to answer this, and if they do, they probably usually charge for those answers!

Answer (score 3):

You need a legal expert but here are just a few of the things you will need to worry about
1. federal and state liscencing 
2. trademarking
3. land rights and water rights 
Are you talking about buying a distillery or building one? because each has its own slew of problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the US, the very first thing you should do is engage a lawyer who specializes in this.

Comment: Agreed: brewing beer or wine is legal, distilling is not.

Answer (score 0):

Get an agent and talk to the folks at TLC